# How to extract the number of lines from the wc command output

Tags: wc

When running `wc -l models.txt`, we get the output which looks like `2113 models_work.txt`. I wonder how to get the `2113` from that output using the `cut` command or something along those lines. It doesn't work when combined with the `cut` command like `wc -l models.txt | cut -f1`. Any help would be appreciated! Tks!

Comment: `wc -l < models.txt` for a single file, because `wc` will not then show any filename.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant what a great comment! Tks!

Comment: Side note: it does work with `cut`, you just need to cut at spaces, not at tabs: `cut -d ' '`

Comment: it seems that `cut` does not have the option `-d`, @KamilMaciorowski!

Comment: A quite limited `cut` then, as `-d` is in the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html).

Comment: If what you want is the number of lines without the filename, then `awk END {print NR} models_work.txt` will give exactly that without needing to pipe it into another command.